# Replace all non-alphanumeric exception between brackets in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to remove all non-alphanumeric characters except brackets and what's between them in python.

For example :

```
My son's birthday [[David | David Smith]] $$ (is) "today" 2019 ][
```

become

```
My son s birthday [[David | David Smith]] is today 2019
```

Here's my function for now :

```
def clean(texte):
    return re.sub(r"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", " ", texte).lower()
```

It replace all non-alphanumeric like I want but it replace the square brackets and the pipe inside. I don't know how to add new regex in the sub method and adding a new condition.

Comment: I think you mean "I would like to *remove* all non-alphanumeric characters *except* brackets and what's between them in python."

Comment: Try `re.sub(r"(\[\[.*?]])|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]", r"\1", texte).lower()` if you need to *remove* those non-alphanumeric chars. Your code is actually replacing with a space. If you need to replace with a space, `re.sub(r"(\[\[.*?]])|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]", lambda x: x.group() if x.group(1) else " ", texte).lower()`. Then, you might need to shrink spaces as a postprocessing step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing you might select what you want to keep using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to either match from `[[` till `]]` or `|` match 1+ times a word character `\w+` and then join the parts back to a string.

```
\[\[[^]]+\]\]|\w+
```

That will match

- `\[\[[^]]+\]\]` match from `[[` till `]]` using a negated character class
- `|` Or
- `\w+` Match 1+ times a word character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UeJh7n/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FykbLA)

For example:

```
import re
regex = r"\[\[[^]]+\]\]|\w+"
test_str = "My son's birthday [[David | David Smith]] $$ (is) \"today\" 2019 ]["
res = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(' '.join(res))
# My son s birthday [[David | David Smith]] is today 2019
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use an alternation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x = "My son's birthday [[David | David Smith]] $$ (is) \"today\" 2019 ]["

def clean(texte):
    return re.sub(r"[^\[\[[^\]\]+\]\]|\w]+", " ", texte).lower()

print(clean(x))

>>> 'my son s birthday [[david | david smith]] is today 2019 ]['
```

Then you could do a split of "]" and keep the first index.

Comment: But I don't want to keep `|` outside the brackets. For example "abd | jde[|]" should give "abd jde[|]"

Comment: @Jack There is no `|` outside the brackets.

Comment: Also, the OP wants to replace all non-alphanumeric characters except when in brackets. Your code fails at that: with `x = "$ [[David $$$]]"`, the `$$$` shouldn't be removed, but your code gives ` [[david ]]`.