# Match by "," ",[" or "]," second alternative is not working

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the regex:

```
(?:,)(?![^[]*\])|(?:,\[)(?![^[]*\])|(?:\],)(?![^[]*\])
```

which is supposed to find all of the  `,  ,[  or ]`,  in a string however the second or statement `(?:,\[)(?![^[]*\])` does not work but the other two do.

input : `file,[test],10,10,[something],[something else]`
desired output: `file test 10 10 something something else`
actual output : `file [test 10 10 [something [something else`

Comment: Please show an example of input and desired result.

Comment: If you want to find all those characters, what's wrong with just `[,\[\]]`?

Comment: input : `file,[test],10,10,[something],[something else]`
desired output: `file test 10 10 something something else`
actual output : `file [test 10 10 [something [something else`

Comment: Put it in the question

Comment: If the brackets have commas inside them, I don't want those to be matched

Comment: Regular expressions are really bad at distinguishing "inside" and "outside". You need a better parser.

Comment: your example should include the case where it shouldn't match. Otherwise it looks like you can just replace all those punctuation characters with space.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813381/replace-all-non-alphanumeric-exception-between-brackets-in-python

Comment: For removing any square brackets and comma, try [like this demo](https://tio.run/##TYzBCsMgEETv@xWLJ6USWnrulxgpFLaJYFTcDaRfb5VSCAzD8GBe@cia0721sJVcBSsBVFrowAdW5WY/O@svCkCI5clSO1fvEMm6Qby9XUcc541kDWnxp40UmbwaRt6jDCVNvL/0yWxRYa@/3ky9QtEGoNSQBPXva1r7Ag). I guess that's what Barmar mentions in his second comment.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more examples, with boundary conditions, like with some commas that should not be deleted, possibly *nested* brackets, double commas, ...etc, ...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the order in your pattern. You noticed correctly that the expressions consume the part of the strings that they match and that there exist special expressions to hold them from consuming parts of the string. However, if you use such expression, you might end up with some remaining characters:

```py
import re

patterns = [r"[,\[\]]",  #1
            r"[,(\],\[)(,\[)(\],)]",  #2
            r"(\],\[)|(,\[)|(\],)|,",  #3
            r",\[?|\],",  #4
            r"(\],\[)|(,\[?)|\],"  #5
            r"(\](?=,))|((?<=,)\[)|,"  #6
            ]
for pat in patterns:
    print(re.sub(pat, " ", input))
```

> `file  test  10 10  something   something else`
> `file  test  10 10  something   something else`
> `file test 10 10 something something else`
> `file test 10 10 something [something else`
> `file test 10 10 something something else`
> `file  test  10 10  something   something else`

The first two patterns replace every character separately and thus yield to double or even triple spaces if the characters are followed by each other. #3 does a good job, the key is that we first look for the most complex pattern `\],\[` and afterwards for the less complex patterns `\],`, `,\[` and `,`. This becomes clear if you check out #4 in comparison. The last pattern (#5) is just a fancy rewriting of #5. Pattern #6 is perhaps what you intended to do in the first place. It looks for brackets with a preceding/following coma but consumes neither of the comas. Only afterwards it replaces all comas again. However this cascaded checking results in multiple spaces again.